# Continuously getting error in KNN Algorithm - elbow method?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I am having problem in this elbow method.

```
error_rate = []
for i in range(1,40):    
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i)
    knn.fit(X_train,y_train)
    pred_i = knn.predict(X_test)
    error_rate.append(np.mean(pred_i != y_test))
```

The last line of code is causing problem:

```
ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 1: given 300
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that the shapes of `pred_i` and `y_test` are equivalent. They should be rank-1 arrays.

```py
print(pred_i.shape) # output: (n_test_sample, )
print(y_test.shape) # output: (n_test_sample, )
```